# Override addFrameScript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a class that contains a movieclip skin (it's named _skin) so users can freely change the appearance of the class. Because of this, I am overriding a lot of functions so they call the skin instead (e.g, gotoAndPlay/Stop functions). The one function I can't figure out how to override, though, is the addFrameScript function because it takes a variable amount of arguments.

Also this is an undocumented function, so here is a post Senocular made on it: http://goo.gl/X5beH

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
override public function addFrameScript(...rest):void {
    super(rest);
}
```

I'm a little concerned though, about what you might be trying to do by overriding this function.  This is used internally by Flash to assign all those framescripts you might be using in the Flash IDE to the compiled MovieClips.

There is probably more information out there regarding the subject, but as for how you'd ideally use the function, I have this blog entry on the topic.

[Mommy, where do Frame Scripts come from?](http://www.scriptocalypse.com/?p=101)

Comment: Man... it was that easy? hahaha. And yeah i know this is what flash uses to build those scripts, but for my uses it should be ok. Thanks for the heads up though! :)